# Incorrect position of node using display: flex and getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, getboundingclientrect

Parent node (`document.body`) has properties

```
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
```

and children (`HTMLDivElement[]`)

```
    width: 12.5em;
    height: 20em;
```

What I'm doing is, let the browser (Firefox 112.0.1 (32-bit)) place all the children via `body.append(...)` and then grab their positions with `getBoundingClientRect()`, then put positions back as style properties adding `position: absolute`. I expect that positions of children stay same but instead every child has horizontal offset of half of their width according to their left-hand neighbour (overlapping each other). Delay between rendering and repositioning does not matter. What am I doing wrong?

Expecting that all the elements after described procedure visually stay same, no overlapping, no nothing.

Comment: That's just what `position: absolute` does to you.

Comment: I don't understand the issue.
Can you share a image reference of what are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more code, say enough to show what you do with 3 or 4 elements being created. For example, who has position relative, and are you getting all the positions first and then doing the changes or are you doing them one by one? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @code absolute is doing ok. every child of parent flexed with "justify-content: center" somehow has the origin of domrect at the very center of self, not left top corner how it should be, that's the thing. according to specs of getBoundingClientRect that is not correct behavior, or am i loosing something

Comment: Without seeing relevant code we can’t help.